# Sending stock status form as email

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am looking for a solution to email my product confirmation page (with available inputs) with the same HTML Result. I am little confused about getting input from the confirmation page on my mail.php . Please find the code below. Thanks

***stockdetailform.php***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stockr Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Stock Form</h1>
<form action="confirmation.php" method="post">
  <p> Enter Total No. of  iPad Air2:
    <input type="text" name="ipadair2" size="30">
  </p>
  <p> Enter Total No. of iPhone6:
    <input type="text" name="iphone6" size="30">
  </p>
  <p> Enter Total No. of iMac:
    <input type="text" name="imac" size="30">
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Generate Report</button>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***confirmation.php***

```
<html>
<title>Confirm Order</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:850px;  margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:150px;">
  <h2>Confirm Order</h2>
  <?php 


 //Get the input.
$ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
$iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6']; 
$imac = $_POST['imac']; 

 //Compute totals.
  $stock_total = $ipadair2 + $iphone6 + $imac ;
    //Output totals.

    if(isset($_POST['ipadair2']) && is_numeric($_POST['ipadair2'])){
 $ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
} else {
 $ipadair2 = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['iphone6']) && is_numeric($_POST['iphone6'])){
 $iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6'];
} else {
 $iphone6 = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['imac']) && is_numeric($_POST['imac'])){
 $imac= $_POST['imac'];
} else {
 $imac= 0;
}

    ?>
  <table width="850" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
    <tr bgcolor="#f7f7f7" >
      <th width="696" height="37" align="left" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">Product</th>
      <th width="128" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
if($ipadair2 > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">ipadair2</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $ipadair2; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <?php
if($iphone60 > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">iphone6</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $iphone6; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <?php
if($imac > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">imac</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $imac; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <tr>
      <td   height="55" ><strong>Total Items</strong></td>
      <td align="center" width="128"><?php print $quote_total; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td colspan="2"><form method="post" action="mail.php">
      <input type='hidden' name='ipadair2' value='<?php if(isset($ipadair2) && $ipadair2 >0){echo $ipadair2;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='iphone6' value='<?php if(isset($iphone6) && $iphone6 >0){echo $iphone6;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>
```

0){echo $imac;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>
           /td>

***mail.php***

```
<?php

/* Subject and email variables */

$emailsSubject = 'STOCK STATUS';
$webMaster  = 'maxcomtesting@gmail.com';

 //Get the input.
$ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
$iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6']; 
$imac = $_POST['imac']; 

 //Compute totals.
  $stock_total = $ipadair2 + $iphone6 + $imac ;
    //Output totals.

    if(isset($_POST['ipadair2']) && is_numeric($_POST['ipadair2'])){
 $ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
} else {
 $ipadair2 = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['iphone6']) && is_numeric($_POST['iphone6'])){
 $iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6'];
} else {
 $iphone6 = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['imac']) && is_numeric($_POST['imac'])){
 $imac= $_POST['imac'];
} else {
 $imac= 0;
}

    ?>

$body = <<<EOD

<table width="850" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
    <tr bgcolor="#f7f7f7" >
      <th width="696" height="37" align="left" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">Product</th>
      <th width="128" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
if($ipadair2 > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">ipadair2</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $ipadair2; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <?php
if($iphone60 > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">iphone6</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $iphone6; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <?php
if($imac > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">imac</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $imac; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <tr>
      <td   height="55" ><strong>Total Items</strong></td>
      <td align="center" width="128"><?php print $quote_total; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td colspan="2"><form method="post" action="mail.php">
      <input type='hidden' name='ipadair2' value='<?php if(isset($ipadair2) && $ipadair2 >0){echo $ipadair2;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='iphone6' value='<?php if(isset($iphone6) && $iphone6 >0){echo $iphone6;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>


<input type='hidden' name='imac' value='<?php if(isset($imac) && $imac >0){echo $imac;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>

    <input type="submit" value="SEND MAIL" name='submit' >/td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

/* This is what sends the email */
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailsSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results Rendered as Html */
echo file_get_contents("http://yourdomain.com/after-message-sent/");

?>
```

***Following result (email) is getting now***

[image]

[image]

***mail.php without any calculations***

```html
<?php 

 //Get the input.
$ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
$iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6']; 
$imac = $_POST['imac']; 


/* Subject and email variables */

$emailsSubject = 'STOCK STATUS';
$webMaster  = 'sample@gmail.com';



/* What You Want To See In The Email Place Inbetween $body = <<<EOD  and EOD; */    
$body = <<<EOD

<table width="850" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" >
      <th width="696" height="37" align="left" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; font-size:18px;">Product</th>
      <th width="128" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; font-size:18px;">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
 
 <tr bgcolor="#F9F9F9" >
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;"><strong>iPadair2</strong></td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; color:#15c; font-weight:bold;">$ipadair2</td>
    </tr>
 <tr >
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;"><strong>iPhone6</strong></td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; color:#15c;font-weight:bold;">$iphone6</td>
    </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#F9F9F9">
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;"><strong>iMac</strong></td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; color:#15c;font-weight:bold;">$imac</td>
    </tr>
 
</table>
<br />
<br />



EOD;

/* Headers is a tag containing the users email and how you want it to display in your email */

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

/* This is what sends the email */
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailsSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results Rendered as Html */
echo file_get_contents("http://yourdomain.com/after-message-sent/");

?>
```

Comment: Code snippets are for providing runnable demos using HTML/CSS/JS. It doesn't run PHP. Use normal code blocks for other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected a few mistake, ie stock_total wasn't set etc, Should work now

```html
Stackdetail.php
<html>
<head>
<title>Stockr Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Stock Form</h1>
<form action="confirmation.php" method="post">
 <label for ="email">Enter your Email
 <input type="email" name="email" />
 </label>
  <p> Enter Total No. of  iPad Air2:
    <input type="text" name="ipadair2" size="30">
  </p>
  <p> Enter Total No. of iPhone6:
    <input type="text" name="iphone6" size="30">
  </p>
  <p> Enter Total No. of iMac:
    <input type="text" name="imac" size="30">
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Generate Report</button>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Confirmation

<html>
<title>Confirm Order</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:850px;  margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:150px;">
  <h2>Confirm Order</h2>
  <?php 


 //Get the input.
$ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
$iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6']; 
$imac = $_POST['imac']; 
$email= $_POST['email'];
 //Compute totals.
  $stock_total = $ipadair2 + $iphone6 + $imac ;
    //Output totals.

    if(isset($_POST['ipadair2']) && is_numeric($_POST['ipadair2'])){
 $ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
} else {
 $ipadair2 = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['iphone6']) && is_numeric($_POST['iphone6'])){
 $iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6'];
} else {
 $iphone6 = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['imac']) && is_numeric($_POST['imac'])){
 $imac= $_POST['imac'];
} else {
 $imac= 0;
}

    ?>
  <table width="850" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
    <tr bgcolor="#f7f7f7" >
      <th width="696" height="37" align="left" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">Product</th>
      <th width="128" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
if($ipadair2 > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">ipadair2</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $ipadair2; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <?php
if($iphone6 > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">iphone6</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $iphone6; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <?php
if($imac > 0){
?>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">imac</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><?php print $imac; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <tr>
      <td   height="55" ><strong>Total Items</strong></td>
      <td align="center" width="128"><?php print $stock_total; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td colspan="2"><form method="post" action="mail.php">
   Your Confirmation email will be sent to : <?php echo " $email "; ?> 
   <input type='hidden' name="email" value='<?php if(isset($email)){echo $email;}?>'>
 <input type='hidden' name='imac' value='<?php if(isset($imac) && $imac >0){echo $imac;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>
      <input type='hidden' name='ipadair2' value='<?php if(isset($ipadair2) && $ipadair2 >0){echo $ipadair2;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='iphone6' value='<?php if(isset($iphone6) && $iphone6 >0){echo $iphone6;}else{echo "0";} ?>'>
<input type="submit" value="Confirm Order" />
        
        mail.php
        
        <?php

/* Subject and email variables */

$emailsSubject = 'STOCK STATUS';
$webMaster  = 'maxcomtesting@gmail.com';
$email= $_POST['email']; //Get the input.
$ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
$iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6']; 
$imac = $_POST['imac']; 

 //Compute totals.
  $stock_total = $ipadair2 + $iphone6 + $imac ;
    //Output totals.

    if(isset($_POST['ipadair2']) && is_numeric($_POST['ipadair2'])){
 $ipadair2 = $_POST['ipadair2'];
} else {
 $ipadair2 = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['iphone6']) && is_numeric($_POST['iphone6'])){
 $iphone6 = $_POST['iphone6'];
} else {
 $iphone6 = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['imac']) && is_numeric($_POST['imac'])){
 $imac= $_POST['imac'];
} else {
 $imac= 0;
}

$body = '
<table width="850" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
    <tr bgcolor="#f7f7f7" >
      <th width="696" height="37" align="left" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">Product</th>
      <th width="128" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;">Quantity</th>
    </tr>';
 
   
if($ipadair2 > 0){
$body.='
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">ipadair2</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;">'.$ipadair2.'</td>
    </tr>';
    
}

if($iphone6 > 0){
$body.=
    '<tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">iphone6</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;">'. $iphone6.'</td>
    </tr>';
    
}
if($imac > 0){
$body.='
    <tr>
      <td height="32" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">imac</td>
      <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc;">'. $imac.'</td>
    </tr>';
    }
 
 $body .='
    <tr>
      <td   height="55" ><strong>Total Items</strong></td>
      <td align="center" width="128">'.$stock_total.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td colspan="2"><form method="post" action="mail.php">';
   
$body .=" <input type='hidden' name='email' value='$email'>
<input type='hidden' name='ipadair2' value='$ipadair2'>
<input type='hidden' name='iphone6' value='$iphone6'>
<input type='hidden' name='imac' value='$imac'>
 <input type='submit' value='SEND MAIL' name='submit' ></td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
 

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

/* This is what sends the email */
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailsSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results Rendered as Html */
//echo file_get_contents("http://yourdomain.com/after-message-sent/");
header('location:http://google.com');exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edit my confirmation page with the above method. But having trouble with mail.php.

Comment: comment out the whole of mail.php and at the top put <?php print_r(S_POST); ?> and see what vars are coming across. did you change all the inputs to the above , not just the one ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated all the hidden inputs. Also added "<?php print_r(S_POST); ?>" but it is not showing any result.Can you please check mail.php code which I have updated now.Once I submit the form, I am getting plain HTML table and php code in [code] format. Please find the email screenshot I am getting now.

Comment: you're closing php before the $body var, take out the closing ?> try that, going out in a second so back in a while, not sure if you can do calculations in the heredoc, and the way you're dropping in and out of php is wrong in a few places, it's not being opened and closed properly. I would suggest putting the table top in a body var, then doing your checks for items and concantenate on to the $body as req'd rather than doing a heredoc. give me a mo.

Comment: Hi Billy, I have updated mail.php. Now I am getting just a Blank Page as email. Thanks for the help. I think I have to revise the confirmation.php code to pass exact values. Thanks again.

Comment: at the top of the confirmation.php do a print_r(S_POST); and what is the result

Comment: Hi, it is just showing "S_POST". No other elements are showing.

Comment: sorry that should be print_r($_POST); it should be a dollar sign

Comment: Now I am getting the following result. Sorry I am not keen in PHP, just a newcomer :) Doing both Design and Front-End.

                              Array ( [ipadair2] => 125 [iphone6] => 50 [b2] => [imac] => [submit] => Submit )

Comment: is some of your code missing off confirmation.php ? give me 10, I 'm going through it all and testing on my comp.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting result on my Email. But it also shows input which doesn't have values. I will add one more screenshot and mail.php code which I am using now. Thanks again.

Comment: Please check the screenshot added

Comment: bear in mind that to send from localhost, ie xampp, you need extra settings. Do an internet search

Comment: Hi Billy. Wonderful!!. Thank you very much. It works great. But mail.php is showing table and not redirecting anywhere. Is there solution please.

Comment: edited, I was only echo'ing out the table to show the email that would be sent. I've removed the echo and added a header('location:google.com');exit; after mail sent, change it to whatever page you want to go to. I fyou could maark the answer so it closes the question aswell, Cheers

Comment: Thanks dear. When update the code I got the following warning but message is delivered.---------   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mail.php:171) in /mail.php on line 180. So I just removed "echo $body;" on line 171. Now it works perfect. Amazing job you have done and saved my life :) Much appreciated. Thank you very much.Cheers...